# Custom Object in Resource File

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, winforms

Based on [a TypeConverter article for making custom resource objects](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10235/Type-converters-your-friendly-helpers), the following code is working correctly:

```
string file = @".\SomeResources.resx";
using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(file))
{
    resx.AddResource("test", "me");
    resx.AddResource("when", DateTime.Now);
    resx.AddResource("custom", new LogPair { Key = "check", Value = "clear" });
}
using (ResXResourceSet resxSet = new ResXResourceSet(file))
{
    var check = (LogPair)resxSet.GetObject("custom", true);
}
```

Most notably, I am successfully retrieving the custom `LogPair` object instance.

I then use resgen to compile the resx into a resource file, and then execute this code:

```
var stuff = ResourceManager.CreateFileBasedResourceManager("SomeResources", ".", null);
string res = stuff.GetString("test");
var info = (LogPair)stuff.GetObject("custom");
var now = (DateTime)stuff.GetObject("when");
```

The string `res` is fetched correctly, giving the value of "me".  The `DateTime` is also fetched correctly.  However, the `info` variable is set to null.  So then I use Visual Studio to peek at the resource file that resgen generated.  It shows that my custom object was converted to a null type (hex value of zero).

So the issue appears to be in resgen itself.  I also learned that the issue is related to my custom TypeConverter.  My custom TypeConverter is used to (de-)serialize my `LogPair` as JSON.  Notice the resx file below:

```
  <data name="test" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>me</value>
  </data>
  <assembly alias="mscorlib" name="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <data name="when" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib">
    <value>07/30/2014 13:23:59</value>
  </data>
  <assembly alias="Serve.Shared.Apis.Injection.Test" name="Serve.Shared.Apis.Injection.Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <data name="custom" type="Injection.Test.LogPair, Serve.Shared.Apis.Injection.Test">
    <value>{"Key":"check","Value":"clear"}</value>
  </data>
```

Again, I can read the above resx succuessfully.  There is only a problem when I use resgen to compile it to a resource file.  I used this command:

```
Resgen /r:Serve.MyAssemblyName.dll SomeResources.resx
```

No errors are reported by resgen.

If I abandon my custom TypeConverter, and allow resgen to use standard binary serialization (and a CDATA seciton, etc., etc.) then everything works fine.

In short, resgen does not like my custom TypeConverter - even though resource files are designed to work with custom TypeConverters.

How do I fix this?